# Numpy difference between neighboring elements

Tags: python, numpy

I have algorithm of calculation of the difference between neighboring elements in pure python:

```
    a = range(1000000) #it's numpy array in my case
    prev = a[0]
    b = [0, ]
    for i in a[1:]:
        b.append(i - prev)
        prev = i
```

Is there any way to rewrite this functions with Numpy?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is the [`diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) method:

```
a = range(5) # python list of numpy array
np.diff(a)
```

returns

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Also, if you didn't know about `np.diff` you could vectorise that into `a[1:] - a[:-1]`.

Comment: @ecatmur - good point. anyway, `diff` works on python lists too. `a[1:] - a[:-1]` on numpy array only.

Comment: There is a slight difference in the size of results: in the question b as same length as a. Not that big of a problem though.

Comment: Result of `np.diff` is one element shorter. You can prepend it with a zero if you wish.

Comment: note that `np.diff(a)` may be slower than `a[1:]-a[:-1]`.

Answer (score 3):

Because he said

> #it's numpy array in my case,

you may want to use `a[1:]-a[:-1]` as it's faster.

```py
> %%timeit a=np.random.rand(10000)
> a[1:]-a[:-1]
6.94 µs ± 188 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

> %%timeit a=np.random.rand(10000)
> np.diff(a)
15.7 µs ± 247 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```